# Firebase Functions Error (Node js; Typescript): No Firebase APP has been created - call initializeApp()

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy 2 firebase functions.
My problem is that I get the following error:

> No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).

Even Though I do, my code in the index.ts file looks like this:

```
import {ENV_VAR} from "./utils/env.js";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
const firebaseConfig = {
 apiKey: ENV_VAR.VITE_APIKEY,
 authDomain: ENV_VAR.VITE_AUTHDOMAIN,
 projectId: ENV_VAR.VITE_PROJECTID,
 storageBucket: ENV_VAR.VITE_STORAGEBUCKET,
 messagingSenderId: ENV_VAR.VITE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
 appId: ENV_VAR.VITE_APPID,
 measurementId: ENV_VAR.VITE_MEASUREMENTID,
};
admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
import {sendMail} from "./sendmail.js";
import {configurationadded} from "./onsubscriptionadded.js";

exports.onsubscription = configurationadded;
exports.sendMail = sendMail;
```

[edit]
The code worked before I did some refactoring.
I think the error is produced in the following code:

```
import {Timestamp} from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import {Configuration} from "./interfacedefinitions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

/**
 * Add two numbers.
 * @param {Configuration} configuration configuration.
 * @param {any} chosenExercices The second number.
 * @param {boolean} send boolean.
 * @return {Promise} The sum of the two numbers.
*/
export function saveTraningsPlan(configuration: Configuration,
  chosenExercices: any,
  send: boolean) {
  // save a new tranings plan
  const serverDate = Timestamp.now();
  const userDate = serverDate.toDate().toLocaleString("en-US",
    {timeZone: configuration.time_zone});
  const userTimeZone = configuration.time_zone;

  return admin.firestore().collection("trainingplans").add({
    "email": configuration.email,
    "unixsystemdate": serverDate,
    "unixlocalizeddate": userDate,
    "usertimezone": userTimeZone,
    "chosenexercices": chosenExercices,
    "send": send,
  });
}
```

[/edit]

Any suggestions why this error occurs?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Which line of code causes that error?  I'm thinking it's not anything you're showing here.  There should be enough information in the question that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I added the code where the error occurs.

Comment: Which line of code causes the error?  How does `saveTraningsPlan` get invoked?  There's not enough here that some one could copy and paste to run on their own exactly as yours runs.  I suggest reading about how to build a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example), which is important for posts here.  You might end up having to remove a lot of unnecessary code to get to the root problem that has an obvious cause.